# How to prevent ConcurrentModificationException when modifying an ArrayAdapter from multiple threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have a RecyclerView which holds a list of files. The user can tap on a number of RecyclerView rows and then upload the selected files. Once a file has been uploaded (on a background thread) I want to delete that row from the RecyclerView.

However, I am receiving the error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at UploadActivity$11$1.onFinish(UploadActivity.java:471)
    at FileUploader.upload(FileUploader.java:115)
    at UploadActivity$11.run(UploadActivity.java:458)
```

I understand that I have multiple threads accessing and modifying my RecyclerView adapter at the same time, but I am unsure how to fix the problem (my code and attempt are posted below).

---

**First I loop through the selected RecyclerView items, get each selected file, and call upload()**

```
// Loop through all selected RecyclerView items 
for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndicies.size(); i++) {

    // Get the i-th selected item
    Upload_Item_Model selectedItem = adapter.getFilteredData().get(selectedIndicies.get(i));

    // Get the file associated with the i-th selected item
    SaveFile file = getFileWithFilename(token, selectedItem.getTitle(), UploadActivity.this);

    // Upload the file
    uploadFile(file);
}
```

**Then I start a new thread, start the upload, and define the onFinish() callback**

```
public void uploadFile(SaveFile saveFile) {

    ...

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // 
            // Uploads the given file, when the upload is complete
            // the onFinish() method is called and the file is passed
            // back so I can update the RecyclerView
            //

            FileUploader.upload(saveFile, new FileUploader.FileUploadListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFinish(SaveFile file) {

                    // Loop through all items in RecyclerView
                    for (Upload_Item_Model item : adapter.getFilteredData()) { // this is line 471 where the crash happens

                        //
                        // If the RecyclerView item has the same name
                        // as the returned file, then it is 
                        // the file I just uploaded
                        //

                        if (item.getTitle().equals(file.getFilename())) {
                            runOnUiThread(() -> {

                                // Removes the item from the adapter
                                adapter.removeItem(item);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**In the adapter I have the following functions which access and modify the adapters ArrayList. I have attempted to make these thread safe with no luck.**

```
public ArrayList<Upload_Item_Model> getFilteredData() {
    synchronized (this.filteredData) {
        return this.filteredData;
    }
}

public void removeItem(Upload_Item_Model item) {
    synchronized (this.filteredData) {
        this.filteredData.remove(item);
    }
}
```

---

Any help or advice is appreciated!

---

**EDIT + SOLUTION**

I wound up getting everything to work using Rajat Mehra's solution of using a single thread to upload all files rather than many threads to upload only one file. I did have to make a minor adjustment to get it to work, but now everything runs smoothly.

```
public void uploadFile() {

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndicies.size(); i++) {

                Upload_Item_Model selectedItem = adapter.getFilteredData().get(selectedIndicies.get(i));

                SaveFile file = getFileWithFilename(token, selectedItem.getTitle(), UploadActivity.this);
                FileUploader.upload(file, new FileUploader.FileUploadListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        runOnUiThread(() -> {

                            // I can now simply use the selectedItem here!
                            adapter.removeItem(selectedItem);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making multiple threads, Create one thread and upload all files One by One in it.

```
public void uploadFile() {


    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //
            // Uploads the given file, when the upload is complete
            // the onFinish() method is called and the file is passed
            // back so I can update the RecyclerView
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndicies.size(); i++) {
                // Get the i-th selected item
                Upload_Item_Model selectedItem = adapter.getFilteredData().get(selectedIndicies.get(i));

                // Get the file associated with the i-th selected item
                SaveFile file = getFileWithFilename(token, selectedItem.getTitle(), UploadActivity.this);
                FileUploader.upload(file, new FileUploader.FileUploadListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish(SaveFile file) {

                        // Loop through all items in RecyclerView
                        for (Upload_Item_Model item : adapter.getFilteredData()) { // this is line 471 where the crash happens

                            //
                            // If the RecyclerView item has the same name
                            // as the returned file, then it is
                            // the file I just uploaded
                            //

                            if (item.getTitle().equals(file.getFilename())) {
                                runOnUiThread(() -> {

                                    // Removes the item from the adapter
                                    adapter.removeItem(item);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception throws when you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, because under the hood `notifyDataSetChanged` do some stuff with your items (without synchronisation) and in the same time you are calling `this.filteredData.remove(item);` and it does not matter with or without synchronized keyword.

Probably first of all you need to call all your `removeItem` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
Like so:

```
for (Upload_Item_Model item: adapter.getFilteredData()) {
 if (item.getTitle().equals(file.getFilename())) {
  runOnUiThread(() -> {
   adapter.removeItem(item);
  });

 }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To think: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not efficient way for updating your recycler view items. There is a `DiffUtil.Callback`, which check difference between two data sets and efficiently dispatch changes to recycler view.